# Show progress while a method is runing in windows application

Tags: multithreading, json, c#-4.0, background, progress-bar

i have an application in c# windows forms (fw4.0) and i have a method that creates a json string and send via post to an action method in a web page. I don't know how much it takes, but i want to show a progress bar while the method is executing. How can i do it?
One idea i have is to perform a counter while the method is running and show it to the user, but i don't know how.. it must be in another thread? how?

I dont have any more helpful information to provide.. i hope you can help me!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use the background worker](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2007/01/wpf-multithreading-with-backgroundworker/) to prevent blocking the UI and to report progress.

Comment: I know about that, but i dont know how can i show the progress of one method that send a post and retrieves an answer.. if the method is between a foreach, for or while loop i will know it how to.. but this method doesnt have any form of "count" the time while it is executing.

Comment: If you don't know the duration set a progress bar to Indeterminate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844833/how-do-you-show-progress-when-indeterminate-true-in-a-wpf-progress-bar You will never know how long a call will take...

Comment: I like that, but i cant find any Intermediate in the ProgressBar object (net4.0 c#). The example you give me is in wpf.. i think in windows forms, there is no Intermediate thing in ProgressBar :S
One thing that may work is a timer that displays the current time while the method is running and stops when the method ends.. but i think i need some knowledge of threading that i dont have :D is that a good idea?

Comment: An intermediate progress bar can be anything. An animated gif image or a text that is constantly bouncing: ".", "..", "...", ".." And learning about threads is very important for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can report progress based on two values:

- prob_time -- the most probable amount of time the action will take to complete;
- max_time -- the maximum amount of time you are willing to wait before considering that the action failed;

You can make the progress bar get to a certain point(e.g. 80%) in prob_time, then to 100% in (max_time-prob_time).

If the action completes faster that max_time, you make the progress jump to 100% and report "Success", otherwise report "Failure"

Answer (score 0):

Finally i did! 
I have to use 2 background workers.. this is what i did..
backgroundWorker1: performs the post method.
backgroundWorker2: performs a TimeSpan counter.
when backgroundWorker2 starts, sets a TimeSpan in 0 and in the DoWork, if the backgroundWorker1 CancellationPending is false, then i report progress in backgroundWorker2.
When the post method finish, i set backgroundWorker1 to CancelAsync, so the backgroundWorker2 will terminate to.
I think that was my best solution.