# WPF Progressbar Stops after a Few Bars

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, progress-bar

In my WPF application i have to show a progressbar progress with in a timer tick event, which i am writing as below,

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
public MainWindow()
{
    timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    this.timer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer_Tick);
}
```

load event as below

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
      progressBar1.Value = DateTime.Now.Second;
      progressBar1.Maximum = 700;
      timer.Start();         
 }
```

And at last in tick event,

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

    //progress bar animation
    System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation doubleanimation = new    System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation(200.0, duration);
    progressBar1.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, doubleanimation);
}
```

When the program's progressbar shows the progress for two-three bars and then it stops increment. Later there is no effect in the progress at all.

Why?

Comment: Why do you use a timer to start the animation? And you are using the wrong timer. `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is for winforms applications. Use [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> In my **WPF** application I have ... `System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;`

That is the wrong type of timer. Use a [DispatcherTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer) instead.

> When i execute my program progressbar shows the progress for two-three bars and then it stops

This surprises me, I wouldn't have expected it to work at all. <strike>This means you may have other problems too, like blocking the main (dispatcher) thread.</strike>

You are only setting the Value once, in the Loaded event:

```cs
     progressBar1.Value = DateTime.Now.Second;
```

There is no change to `progressBar1.Value` in the Tick event. So it figures that it stops moving.

Answer (score 10):

Since your `ProgressBar` doesn't relate to any particular behavior, it looks like a job for an **indeterminate** bar.

[*This other SO question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844833/how-do-you-show-progress-when-isindeterminate-true-in-a-wpf-progress-bar) provides some insight about it. In short, it's a XAML one-liner:

```xml
<!-- MinVal, MaxVal, Height needed for this to work -->
<ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar1" Margin="5" IsIndeterminate="True" 
    MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="700" value="0" Height="20"/>
```

Then in code, you go like this:

```cs
progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = true; // start animation
progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = false; // stop animation
```

Answer (score 4):

Use DispatcherTimer instead of Timer (Forms object), and use Value property of ProgressBar.

Try this:

MainWindows.xaml:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="55" Width="261">
    <Grid>
        <ProgressBar Name="pb" Maximum="60" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindows.xaml.cs:

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private DispatcherTimer timer;
    
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            this.timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            this.timer.Interval = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            this.timer.Start();
        }

        private void timer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.pb.Value = System.DateTime.Now.Second % 100;
        }
    }
}
```

You can change the behaviour of the progress bar by changing the Value property (don't forget defining the Maximum property in the xaml).

Answer (score 3):

I found this ([WPF Multithreading: Using the BackgroundWorker and Reporting the Progress to the UI. link](http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/03/wpf-multithreading-using-the-backgroundworker-and-reporting-the-progress-to-the-ui/)) to contain a great solution for my needs, albeit with a dialog box.

The one thing I found very useful was that the worker thread couldn't access the MainWindow's controls (in its own method). However, when using a delegate inside the main windows event handler, it was possible.

```cs
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    pd.Close();
    // Get a result from the asynchronous worker
    T t = (t)args.Result
    this.ExampleControl.Text = t.BlaBla;
};
```