# Auto increment BackgroundWorker 's ProgressBar

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

How to autoincrement ProgressBar instead of calling bgWorker.ReportProgress(x)? (I use C#, WPF Application).

Problem is that within BackgroundWorker's work I call external library that do a lot of work and I want to update ProgressBar while library working. I can estimate time needed for running external method.

I tried using Timer, but that doesn't work, because I can't access to bgWorker from another thread.

In other words, I need something like this:

```
bgWorker.StartPercentage = 40;
bgWorker.FinishPercentage = 80;
bgWorker.ProgressBarUpdateTime = 20000; // estimated time needed to run external library
bgWorker.StartProgressBarUpdate();
ExternalLibrary.CallMethod(); // it takes about 20 sec to run this, bgWorker should
     // update ProgressBar, while method is working
bgWorker.ReportProgress(80); // correct ProgressBar value
// do rest of work
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Which Timer did you try to use? If you are estimating the time why did you access bgWorker from another thread instead of the ProgressBar? Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429256/wpf-progressbar

Comment: Why not just use some type of hour glass?  What do you do if it does not finish in 20 seconds?

Comment: @tim I tried to use System.Timers.Timer. Thanks for link, ProgressBar.BeginAnimations solved my problem, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: @Blam Hour glasses are not suitable in my case, because execution time can be much longer. And, in any case, using ProgressBar is more user friendly than just hour glasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

progressBar.BeginAnimation() do exactly what I want. @tim provided [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429256/wpf-progressbar) that helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a separate background worker for the timer that updates the progress bar.